# How to Add TabItem with Header and Content using WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabitem

All, I have the following XAML in my main window

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            TabStripPlacement="Top">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="TabItem">
              <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
              <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
              <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
           </Style>
      </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>    
</TabControl>
```

this is adding a `TabItem` with the desired content. But the content is not filling the `TabItem`/TabPage. Can someone tell me why?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What type of items are you adding to the `WorkSpaces` collection?

Comment: `Workspaces` is of type `ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>`. Basicall this adds a custom UserControl. I hope this answers your question... Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oh, I see. Your Views are coming out as expected, but then the `Alignment` is not the expected. Right?

Comment: Yeah, the `TabItem` is added with the correct header and content, but the content alignment is set to what _seems_ like`Center` when I have specified `Stretch`.

Comment: use Snoop to inspect the Visual Tree at runtime. That should give you a hint about what's going on.

Comment: That look great. I am new to this and was not aware of this tool at all. I will try it now. Thanks.

Comment: I have just got no idea what I am looking at with that tool. Can you offer any advice based upon what I have shown in the brief example?

Comment: Inspect the View and check what the `Alignment` properties are for each element inside the Content part of the TabControl. Also check to see if there's some fixed Width or Height on any element, which would prevent it from stretching.

Comment: Good man! Great tool! The user Control had a fixed window size that was being set in the XAML. Are you a full time WPF developer and is this a tool you use a lot? Answer the question an I will accept. Thanks again for your time...

Comment: yep, I'm a full time WPF developer, and I can't live without Snoop =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer:

use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the Visual Tree at runtime. That should give you a hint about what's going on.

Inspect the View and check what the `Alignment` properties are for each element inside the Content part of the `TabControl`. Also check to see if there's some fixed `Width` or `Height` on any element, which would prevent it from stretching